# How do I deal with having a massive amount of conditions on an if-than statement?

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

I recently built a Tic Tac Toe game in Objective-C, while focusing on trying to make my code as short and clean as possible (as I'm relatively new to programming, this is my first time focusing on making something efficient/readable instead of just making it work at any cost)

For the most part, I was able to make my code short and efficient enough that I was happy with it - except for the part of the checkWin function that checks if either X or O has won the game

I have an NSArray Object called "BoardState", with the indexes 0-8 corresponding to the 9 spots on the board like so

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

When an index is set to 0, it's considered blank. 1 is X, 2 is O.

However, the only way I could figure out how to check if X or O has won is to manually go over the entire board with an if statement and check every possibility, like so

```
if  (
    ([_boardState[0] isEqual:@1]  &&
     [_boardState[1] isEqual:@1]  &&
     [_boardState[2] isEqual:@1]) ||

    ([_boardState[3] isEqual:@1]  &&
     [_boardState[4] isEqual:@1]  &&
     [_boardState[5] isEqual:@1]) ||

    ([_boardState[6] isEqual:@1]  &&
     [_boardState[7] isEqual:@1]  &&
     [_boardState[8] isEqual:@1]) ||

    ([_boardState[0] isEqual:@1]  &&
     [_boardState[3] isEqual:@1]  &&
     [_boardState[6] isEqual:@1]) ||

    ([_boardState[1] isEqual:@1]  &&
     [_boardState[4] isEqual:@1]  &&
     [_boardState[7] isEqual:@1]) ||

    ([_boardState[2] isEqual:@1]  &&
     [_boardState[5] isEqual:@1]  &&
     [_boardState[8] isEqual:@1]) ||

    ([_boardState[0] isEqual:@1]  &&
     [_boardState[4] isEqual:@1]  &&
     [_boardState[8] isEqual:@1]) ||

    ([_boardState[2] isEqual:@1]  &&
     [_boardState[4] isEqual:@1]  &&
     [_boardState[6] isEqual:@1])
     ){
    [xWins show];
    [self overWriteBoardState];
}
```

then once again, with O, almost exactly the same thing.

```
if  (
     ([_boardState[0] isEqual:@2]  &&
      [_boardState[1] isEqual:@2]  &&
      [_boardState[2] isEqual:@2]) ||

     ([_boardState[3] isEqual:@2]  &&
      [_boardState[4] isEqual:@2]  &&
      [_boardState[5] isEqual:@2]) ||

     ([_boardState[6] isEqual:@2]  &&
      [_boardState[7] isEqual:@2]  &&
      [_boardState[8] isEqual:@2]) ||

     ([_boardState[0] isEqual:@2]  &&
      [_boardState[3] isEqual:@2]  &&
      [_boardState[6] isEqual:@2]) ||

     ([_boardState[1] isEqual:@2]  &&
      [_boardState[4] isEqual:@2]  &&
      [_boardState[7] isEqual:@2]) ||

     ([_boardState[2] isEqual:@2]  &&
      [_boardState[5] isEqual:@2]  &&
      [_boardState[8] isEqual:@2]) ||

     ([_boardState[0] isEqual:@2]  &&
      [_boardState[4] isEqual:@2]  &&
      [_boardState[8] isEqual:@2]) ||

     ([_boardState[2] isEqual:@2]  &&
      [_boardState[4] isEqual:@2]  &&
      [_boardState[6] isEqual:@2])
     ){
    [oWins show];
    [self overWriteBoardState];
}
```

As a bonus, my overWriteBoardState function that reset the board to a blank slate which cannot be modified anymore. This could also be more efficient

```
-(void)overWriteBoardState {
    self.boardState[0] = @3;
    self.boardState[1] = @3;
    self.boardState[2] = @3;
    self.boardState[3] = @3;
    self.boardState[4] = @3;
    self.boardState[5] = @3;
    self.boardState[6] = @3;
    self.boardState[7] = @3;
    self.boardState[8] = @3;
}
```

How else could I structure this as to avoid these massive piles of repeated lines? Any help or tips is appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel : There is an algorithm called Minimax https://github.com/mattrajca/TTT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use loops. The `overWriteBoardState` method can be written as:

```
- (void)overWriteBoardState {
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        self.boardState[i] = @3;
    }
}
```

The two big `if` statements to see if X or O has won can be made into one `if` statement using a loop:

```
for (NSInteger p = 1; p <= 2; p++) {
    if (
         ([_boardState[0] isEqual:@(p)]  &&
          [_boardState[1] isEqual:@(p)]  &&
          [_boardState[2] isEqual:@(p)]) ||

         ([_boardState[3] isEqual:@(p)]  &&
          [_boardState[4] isEqual:@(p)]  &&
          [_boardState[5] isEqual:@(p)]) ||

         ([_boardState[6] isEqual:@(p)]  &&
          [_boardState[7] isEqual:@(p)]  &&
          [_boardState[8] isEqual:@(p)]) ||

         ([_boardState[0] isEqual:@(p)]  &&
          [_boardState[3] isEqual:@(p)]  &&
          [_boardState[6] isEqual:@(p)]) ||

         ([_boardState[1] isEqual:@(p)]  &&
          [_boardState[4] isEqual:@(p)]  &&
          [_boardState[7] isEqual:@(p)]) ||

         ([_boardState[2] isEqual:@(p)]  &&
          [_boardState[5] isEqual:@(p)]  &&
          [_boardState[8] isEqual:@(p)]) ||

         ([_boardState[0] isEqual:@(p)]  &&
          [_boardState[4] isEqual:@(p)]  &&
          [_boardState[8] isEqual:@(p)]) ||

         ([_boardState[2] isEqual:@(p)]  &&
          [_boardState[4] isEqual:@(p)]  &&
          [_boardState[6] isEqual:@(p)])
         ) {
        if (p == 1) {
            [xWinds show];
        } else {
            [oWins show];
        }
        [self overWriteBoardState];
    }
}
```

With some more looping and some other array data representing matches, the big `if` statement can be converted into simpler form but the big `if` statement may actually be simpler and clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Next time I might try simplifying the massive if statement, but for now you're probably right, it's the simplest solution

Answer (score 2):

Firstly the data storage.  Given you are dealing with a small fixed-sized array of tri-state values, I would suggest using a simple C array of `uint8_t` using the `0`, `1` and `2` encoding you have already mentioned, rather than `NSArray` as Objective-C collection classes can only store objects.

Then you need to study the relationship in each index pattern for lines across and lines down and iterate over the base value.

For example:

```
//
// Keep this in your comments, as it's invaluable:
//
// 0 1 2
// 3 4 5
// 6 7 8
//

BOOL didWinAcross(const uint8_t *board, uint8_t side)
{
    BOOL didWin = NO;
    for (unsigned row = 0; row < 3 && !didWin; row++) {
        didWin =
            board[row * 3 + 0] == side &&
            board[row * 3 + 1] == side &&
            board[row * 3 + 2] == side;
    }
    return didWin;
}

BOOL didWinDown(const uint8_t *board, uint8_t side)
{
    BOOL didWin = NO;
    for (unsigned column = 0; column < 3 && !didWin; column++) {
        didWin =
            board[column + 0] == side &&
            board[column + 3] == side &&
            board[column + 6] == side;
    }
    return didWin;
}

BOOL didWinDiagonal(const uint8_t *board, uint8_t side)
{
    return (
        board[0] == side &&
        board[4] == side &&
        board[8] == side) || (
        board[2] == side &&
        board[4] == side &&
        board[6] == side);
}
```

and then use these functions like this:

```
uint8_t board[9] = ...;
uint8_t sideThatJustMoved = 1;
if (didWinAcross(board, sideThatJustMoved) ||
    didWinDown(board, sideThatJustMoved) ||
    didWinDiagonal(board, sideThatJustMoved)) {
    someoneWon(sideThatJustMoved);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! All the suggestions everyone has given are great, I really appreciate the advice!

Answer (score 1):

First off, I'd recommend using `0` for an empty square as it'll simplify conditionals.

But basically, instead of going through every combination, go through patterns of combinations.

```
- (NSUInteger) winnerStartingAt:(NSUInteger)index withStride:(NSUInteger)stride {
    NSUInteger a = self.boardState[index] ;
    NSUInteger b = self.boardState[index+stride] ;
    NSUInteger c = self.boardState[index+2*stride] ;
    if ( a && a==b && b==c ) // if they're all the same and they're all not empty
        return a ;
    return 0 ; // no winner (non-homogeneous list)
}

- (void) checkBoard {
    NSUInteger winner = 0 ; // assume there's no winner
    // check all the rows, which have a stride of 1
    if(!winner) winner = [self winnerStartAt:0 withStride:1] ;
    if(!winner) winner = [self winnerStartAt:3 withStride:1] ;
    if(!winner) winner = [self winnerStartAt:6 withStride:1] ;
    // check all the columns, which have a stride of 3 (they go downward)
    if(!winner) winner = [self winnerStartAt:0 withStride:3] ;
    if(!winner) winner = [self winnerStartAt:1 withStride:3] ;
    if(!winner) winner = [self winnerStartAt:2 withStride:3] ;
    // check the diagonals
    if(!winner) winner = [self winnerStartAt:0 withStride:4] ;
    if(!winner) winner = [self winnerStartAt:2 withStride:2] ;
    if ( winner )
        // whatever you want to do
}
```

I'd recommend following some other suggestions given, namely using a 2D array of integers instead of a 1D array of objects. This would give performance benefits. At your level, and for Tic Tac Toe, the difference is negligible, but I'd suggest that's the next thing you learn so you know how it's done and know the performance differences of them.

Comment: This is clever but as written, this makes it hard to show whether X or O won.

Comment: True. I couldn't think of a particularly elegant way this morning, but I've edited it to add one.

Comment: Thank you! This is an incredibly clever solution - makes me look at the whole thing in a different way!

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of winning combinations, browse through the list to return the winner (1 or 2).

```
- (int)checkWinnerForBoard:(NSArray*)_boardState
{
    NSArray *tests = @[@[@0, @1, @2], @[@3, @4, @5], @[@6, @7, @8], @[@0, @3, @6], @[@1, @4, @7], @[@2, @5, @8], @[@0, @4, @8], @[@2, @4, @6]];
    for (NSArray *test in tests) {
        int value = [_boardState[[test[0] intValue]] intValue];
        if (value && value == [_boardState[[test[1] intValue]] intValue] && value == [_boardState[[test[2] intValue]] intValue])
            return value;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can store the combination array in your `-init` so you don't recreate it each time.

Alternatively, you might want to only test for the last position played.

```
- (int)checkWinnerForBoard:(NSArray*)_boardState lastposition:(int)lastPosition
{
    NSArray *tests = @[@[@[@1, @2], @[@3, @6], @[@4, @8]], @[@[@0, @2], @[@4, @7]], @[@[@0, @1], @[@5, @8], @[@4, @6]], @[@[@0, @6], @[@4, @5]], @[@[@3, @5], @[@1, @7], @[@0, @8], @[@2, @6]], @[@[@3, @4], @[@2, @8]], @[@[@0, @3], @[@2, @4], @[@7, @8]], @[@[@1, @4], @[@6, @8]], @[@[@2, @5], @[@6, @7], @[@0, @4]]];
    for (NSArray *test in tests[lastPosition]) {
        int value = [_boardState[lastPosition] intValue];
        if (value == [_boardState[[test[0] intValue]] intValue] && value == [_boardState[[test[1] intValue]] intValue])
            return value;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Again, you can store the combination array in your `-init` so you don't recreate it each time.